# Check for request.GET variable in the template

Tags: django, templates

I want to display a certain  in the template only if a certain GET variable is set....I thought using  `{% if request.get.my_var %}` would work, but it's not giving me the results.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Variables are case-sensitive - so, assuming as lazerscience points out that you actually have the request object in the context, you would need to use  `{% if request.GET.my_var %}`.

Comment: This seems to give me an error 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10' when the variable is not set.  To work around this I use {% if 'my_var' in request.GET %}

Answer (score 13):

Check if you have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py`.

If not put it there, or add request yourself to your rendered context.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Answer (score 0):

Passthrough your request.GET parameters to your Django template:
example - we have a page **register/** with certain parameters in the form, and have a duplicate page **registerprint/** without pagination, as a full list of filtered records, and we need to redirect user **from register/ to registerprint/** by passing through some of the parameters from the **register/** page

```
 urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import record_list, record_list_print
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', view=record_list, name='register'),
    path('registerprint/', view=record_list_print, name='registerprint'),
  ]

views.py
def strx(string):
    param=str(string)
    if param=='None':
        return ''
    else:
        return param
def record_list(request):
      req = {'type': strx(request.GET.get('type')),
        'profile' : strx(request.GET.get('profile')),
        'org_nazvanie':strx(request.GET.get('org_nazvanie')),
        'org_filial':strx(request.GET.get('org_filial')),
        'org_tema':strx(request.GET.get('org_tema')),
        'org_address':strx(request.GET.get('org_address')),
        'info_naimenovanie':strx(request.GET.get('info_naimenovanie')),
        'info_forma':strx(request.GET.get('info_forma')),
        'info_dostup':strx(request.GET.get('info_dostup')),
        'all_in_one':strx(request.GET.get('all_in_one'))
    }
    return render(request, 'bot/registerfilterpag.html', { 'req' : req})
```

and the **registerfilterpag.html**. In this template we create a button that redirects user to the duplicate copy of the page, with some of the URL parameters we've extracted in views.py from the initial request. The button itself is not printable, so, the *'noprint'* style is added to the markup.

```
 registerfilterpag.html
 {% extends 'bot/base.html' %}
 {% block Body %}
<style>
@media print {
  .noprint {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
  </style>
    <a class="btn btn-info noprint" role="button" href="../../registerprint/?type={{ req.type }}&profile={{ req.profile }}&org_nazvanie={{ req.org_nazvanie }}&org_filial={{ req.org_filial }}&org_tema={{ req.org_tema }}&org_address={{ req.org_address }}&info_naimenovanie={{ req.info_naimenovanie }}&info_forma={{ req.info_forma }}&info_dostup={{ req.info_dostup }}&all_in_one={{ req.all_in_one }}&submit=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA">version for printing</a>
 {% endblock %}
```